# When given a string as an argument, how may I search an array of structures for a matching string?

Tags: c

I am having difficulties trying to debug the behavior of my code. I am working on a function that, given a string, searches a given array of structures for a matching command name and then calls the function associated with that name.  If the string argument passed to do_file_menu() specifies a menu option not in the array file[ ], the function should print "Invalid menu option." to the screen and return.

When I only use this code:

```
void do_file_menu(char *name)
{
  int i;
  int len = ( sizeof(file)/sizeof(file[0]) );
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
    if (!strcmp(file[i].cmd_name , name)){
      file[i].cmd_ptr();
      break;
    }
  }
 }
```

For the strings that are within the array file[] i get the following (desired) output:

```
Created new file.
Opened file.
File saved.
Printing file...
Goodbye.
```

However, when I attempt to code the "invalid menu option" case as such:

```
void do_file_menu(char *name)
{
  int i;
  int len = ( sizeof(file)/sizeof(file[0]) );
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
    if (!strcmp(file[i].cmd_name , name)){
      file[i].cmd_ptr();
      break;
    }
    else if (strcmp(file[i].cmd_name , name)){
      printf("Invalid menu option.\n");
      break;
    }
  }
 }
```

The output is:

```
Created new file.
Invalid menu option.
Invalid menu option.
Invalid menu option.
Invalid menu option.
Invalid menu option.
Invalid menu option.
Invalid menu option.
```

I am out of ideas. For further reference, there are 8 calls in total to the `do_file_menu()` function. 5 of the calls *are* within the array `file[]`, and 2 are not.

Final, correct output should be:

```
Created new file.
Opened file.
File saved.
Printing file...
Goodbye.
Invalid menu option.
Invalid menu option.
```

Comment: Also note: there is no need for an `else if` following `if (!strcmp(file[i].cmd_name , name))`. No need to call `strcmp()` twice in that case. It's either `0` or it's not. This is a general note to your logic, see Answer for your solution.

Comment: I appreciate the tip. I'm still learning, so this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the "not found" condition *outside* of the loop, *after* you've checked all possible strings in the list and still haven't found the target name:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
...
void do_file_menu(char *name)
{
  int i;
  bool found = false;
  int len = ( sizeof(file)/sizeof(file[0]) );
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
    if (!strcmp(file[i].cmd_name , name)){
      file[i].cmd_ptr();
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!found)
    printf("Invalid menu option.\n");
 }
```